# linear projection $x_{W}=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx$, isn't projector eliminate itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, projection, projection-matrices

[image]

I am wondering isn't this projector itself is identity matrix?

$$x_{W}=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx\\projector=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T=AA^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}A^T=I$$

Thank you for any comment

Comment: $A$ is not necessarily a square matrix. What do you mean by $A^{-1}$?

Comment: The step you made, where you equated $(A^\top A)^{-1}$ with $A^{-1} (A^\top)^{-1}$, works when $A$ is square and invertible. In this case, yes it is the identity; this is the projection onto the columnspace of $A$, which is the entire space, and the identity map is the projector onto the entire space. This formula is for rectangular "tall" matrices with linearly independent columns (so that $(A^\top A)^{-1}$ exists). If $A$ does not have linearly independent columns, you can either reduce the columns to a basis, or you can use the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse.